# Using kotlinx.serialization library with Bazel's rules_kotlin

Tags: kotlin, bazel, kotlinx.serialization

How does one go about using the kotlinx.serialization library with Bazel's rules_kotlin?

This is what I've tried:

```
java_plugin(
    name = "grrr_plugin",
    processor_class = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.backend.jvm.SerializableCodegenImpl",
    deps = ["@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin_maven_serialization"],
)

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "dto",
    srcs = ["src/main/kotlin/Dto.kt"],
    plugins = [":grrr_plugin"],
    deps = [
        "//proto:market_java_proto",
        "@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin_maven_serialization",
        "@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx_serialization_runtime",
    ],
)

@Serializable
data class Foo(val id: String, val bar: Int)
```

, where Foo is a class in the :dto package.

I can build the dto library, but I get

```
unresolved reference: serializer
    val jsonData = json.stringify(Foo.serializer(), foo)
```

when I use the dto library in other packages.